# Swift : UITableViewCell separator for the first the cell only

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to display comments without separator as the image below I tried using the separator but it didn't work I need separator only for the first cell.

[image]

```
     super.viewDidLoad()
    self.commentstableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //post's section == 0

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! postCell


         self.commentstableView.separatorColor = UIColor.grayColor()


    }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! commentCell
        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = comments[indexPath.row]

        return cell



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In StoryBoard, go to your postCell prototype and add a thin UIView and set its background color and height in the Attributes inspector.

But then...

Your logic is garbled and you're shadowing declarations of `cell`, so it will need to fit into the following structure:

**(Edited)**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("postCID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! postCell
        // Additional cell configuration
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! commentCell
        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = comments[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry in your logic I can't add any IBOutlet I get this  error > UITableviewCell does not have a member name "" for each IBOutlet even after adding "as! cell name "

Comment: Yeah, what I gave you can be worked with but it's awkward. Will improve it.

Comment: Then just make sure you de-garble your logic somehow from your posted code. As it stands you're always returning a `commentCell`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a grey view with 1 point height in your first custom cell, and in the rest of cells you don't need this view, and of curse you should hide the separator of the table view so you can show only your custom separator. I hope this helps.